# how to update activeTintColor for react-navigation tab-navigator dynamically?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to update the tab-bar navigator color dynamically, here is my code:

```js
const MyStack = createBottomTabNavigator({ ... }, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: "green",
  }
});

class CustomNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = MyStack.router;
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return <MyStack
      navigation={navigation}
      activeTintColor={"red"}
    />;
  }
}
```

the tab-bar color always "green", and `activeTintColor={"red"}` not works. I also tried this(not works too):

```js
return <MyStack
          navigation={navigation}
          navigatorOptions={{
              tabBarOptions: {
                  activeTintColor: "red",
              }
          }}
        />
```

thanks.

Comment: What color do you get if you don't set the `tabBarOptions` object in your stack?

Comment: default color, blue.

Comment: I have completed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variables to your child..

```js
const MyStack = createBottomTabNavigator({ ... }, {
  tabBarOptions: {[
    {
    activeTintColor: "green",
},
this.props.tabBarOptions
  ]}
});
```

---

```js
class CustomNavigator extends React.Component {
  static router = MyStack.router;
  render() {

    return <MyStack
      activeTintColor={"red"}
    />;
  }
}
```

Comment: this.props is undefined.
`const MyStack = createBottomTabNavigator` is out of class block

Comment: thanks. I solved this by customize the tab bar component, and pass the activeTintColor prop to the component just works.

Comment: @SongZhigang  Could you choose an answer if it was helpful to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the colors with `navigationOptions` in your screens.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'red', // overwrite the default green color
    },
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/change-activetintcolor)

Comment: thanks, but this can't use in the situation which I want to change the color by button press.